# Running proxy server in AWS environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

We have a URL whitelisting to restrict outbound HTTPS connections to specific domains from EC2 hosted applications. We deployed an EC2 instance running proxy software and configure it to accept traffic from all subnets and EC2 instances in the VPC.
I configured the proxy to only pass through traffic to domains you defined in the whitelist. There's a nightly maintenance window (10 minutes) where all instances download files. Each file is about 200MB in size and there are 500 instances in the VPC that routinely fetch files. After a few days I notice that some machines are failing to successfully download files within the maintenance window. The download URLs used for these updates are correctly listed in the proxy's whitelist configuration and we can access them manually using a web browser on the instances. Any idea what the problem could be?

If I add more EIPs to the proxy to increase network throughpout through the Internet Gateway (IGW), will this solve the problem?

Will increasing the EC2 size of the proxy or the size of the NAT instance fix the problem?

Comment: are the same instances failing or you see different instances failing each night? what type is the instance? is it a t2? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits

Answer (score 0):

Look at the cloudwatch metrics network throughput on the proxy.  Smaller instances, like t2.micro, in my experience, seem to have connectivity of about 250Mbits/sec, or roughly 31.25MBytes/sec.  No amount of tweaking will change this, including additional EIPs or ENIs.

This is a limitation of the instance class.  Larger instances have more.  An hi1.4xlarge has in excess of 1Gbit/sec available *to the Internet*, by my benchmarks.

There's a chart of relative Ethernet performance for instance classes [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types)... though they don't cite specific bandwidth numbers.

Of course, if your machine is a t2 and your proxy is not efficient with the processor, it could be using up the CPU credits at some point during your mass downloads.  This metric is also visible in the console.